# Why do I get duplicate define although using require_once()?

Tags: php

My defs.php has a define that I need, and although I used require_once for it, when I try to access defs.php, I get a series of duplicates as if the defs.php was already called before.
On the other hand, if I don't call it, I get undefined `use of undefined constant`...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you included it once before using include()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're using 2 separate paths to the file. I've seen this issues when doing:

```
require_once("somefile.php");
require_once("/full/path/to/somefile.php");
```

I think php keep track of what's been included in a way that doesn't intelligently assess all possible path combinations to the same file and treat it as the same.

I try to avoid using requires and includes by wrapping everything in object and using an autoloader.  For constants, I make an object with a bunch of static properties.